# How to run a static method in separate AppDomain?

Tags: c#, .net, appdomain

I'm using some [xpcom](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/XPCOM) component in my project. This component doesn't tolerate concurrent usage in the same Appdomain.

I can restrict my usage of this component in a single static method :

```
public static class MyClass
{
    // This should run in another appdomain
    public static QueryResult Run(QueryParameter arg) 
    {

    }
}
```

`QueryResult` and `QueryParameter` are both immutable serializable class.

I really prefer to not run it in another process so I think it could be possible to run it in another Appdomain.

What is the correct way to do it ?

Answer (score 0):

Only objects can be passed across appdomain boundaries. Static methods are essentially function pointers. There are roundabout ways of referencing a function pointer across an appdomain boundary--however, when you call it, it will execute in the *calling* appdomain. That's not what you want. Instead, wrap the function in a (non-static) class that derives from MarshalByRefObject, then call the wrapper.

Comment: "There are roundabout ways of referencing a function pointer across an appdomain boundary--however, when you call it, it will execute in the calling appdomain." - I'm interested in exactly this.  I'd like to load "plugin" assemblies in AppDomains purely for unloadability - I'd prefer to execute static plugin methods in my original domain, without referencing their assemblies directly.  I do not need data isolation.  I haven't been able to locate samples of this, and I suspect it is not meant to be possible.  Any suggestions welcome!